# Component kebab-case name not working in template

Tags: vue.js

I have an app with the following structure.

```
-App.vue
-components
  -TodoList.vue
  -TodoItem.vue
```

When I was trying to use TodoItem from TodoList, I import it from TodoItem. But the questions is I need to use the tag `</TodoItem>` but not `</todo-item>` to have it rendered.

I don't quite understand because I have export the name as 'todo-item'. I tried to recreate a To-do list by following Youtube tutorial. It worked when I followed the tutorial step by step. But it didn't when I try to recreate on my own.

This the parent component (todo-list) when I followed the tutorial, it worked without the name pair under components.

```
export default {
  name: 'todo-list',
  components: {
    TodoItem,
  },
```

But I need to specifically name my component in the parent component but trying on my own.

```
export default {
  name: 'todo-list',

  components: {
    'todo-item': TodoItem,
  },
}
```

In the first case I successfully use `</todo-item>` but not the second case returns nothing.

Any help or explanation will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The component `name` property is only useful for two things... recursive components and debugging

Comment: You seem to be missing the all important `components: { TodoItem }` part. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration-in-a-Module-System. Once you have that set, you should be able to use either `<TodoItem>` or `<todo-item>` in your template

Comment: I actually included components in the script, but I dont know when do I needed to name my components explicitly and when do not. (edited my question)

Comment: Thanks Phil. This is exactly the answer I am looking for. I think I should go through the official doc before moving forward!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you alias your components by their lowercase / kebab-cased names, they may only be used like that in your template. Using Pascal-cased names lets you use both.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Name-Casing

With that in mind and following the [Vue style guide recommendations](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/), you should always use Pascal-cased names

```js
import TodoItem from './TodoItem'

export default {
  name: 'TodoList',
  components: {
    TodoItem
  }
}
```

This is just ES6 shorthand for

```js
components: {
  TodoItem: TodoItem
}
```

and will let you use either `<TodoItem>` or `<todo-item>` in your template.